# How to broadcast message to all non connected clients

Tags: messaging

I plan to have server which consumes all data sent from clients. I want to use messaging system (RabbitMQ) to avoid all troubles with discovering services, recoveries and so on. Client just publish the message whenever the message broker is available (whenever the connection is available). So, my server is sink here and it collects all data whenever the data show.

But I don't know how to solve following issue. I want to send message to all clients. I can do publish subscribe, but I will lost all clients which was not connected at this moment.

So my questions are:

- how can I assure that all clients gets the message even when wasn't connected to the server? I don't want to deal with some magic pulls, or with some negotiation of what was already sent, and what wasn't. Another solution is to create and keep the queue for particular client - but I would like to avoid it. Unless I can publish to topic and finally it lands in each of clients queue
- or, how it should be done in general?

EDIT: Is the exchange publishing to the multiple queues for each client with the durable set to true an option?

Comment: If you need to send a series of messages to the clients, you need a queue per client. If the client only needs the latest version of what is on a single queue, you can use one queue for all clients, and have them look at the last entry without removing it, perhaps identifying it as new by using a timestamp.